# 2009 Honda Accord Short Scratching Noise

Tags: honda, starting, cold-start

When turning the key, before the engine starts there is a very short scratching noise (fractions of a second). This happens only during the first time it is started. The sound does not persist. Other than the short scratching noise before the engine starts, the engine sounds completely fine and the car runs without issue. Any idea what this might be? I've been looking at other threads, and people are suggesting it's a starter issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm wondering if the noise is the starter and not the engine. If the starter doesn't fully engage correctly, it will make a loud noise as gears grind against gears.

Comment: Does it happen the second time you start the engine (e.g.: start and run for a minute -> stop the engine -> start again)?